# Зачем использовать grep { $_ }?

Tags: perl

Для чего вообще использовать такой синтаксис? Что это даёт, кроме того, что все элементы массива/массивов складываются в новый массив? Может в этом есть какой-то нюанс, о котором я не знаю?!

Пример:

```
@result = grep { $_ } @arr1, @arr2;
```

Comment: такой синтаксис не положит в @result undef-ы, '' и 0. это простой и не совсем правильный фильтр дефайнутых значений

Comment: @nörbörnën, а! Вот оно как! Всё, понял, спасибо большое. Я просто из двух массивов грепнул, и получил в ризалте то же, что было в 2х массивах.

Comment: не забудь, что он обрежет 0. лучше говорить `defined $_ && $_ ne ''`

Comment: Лучше с пустой строкой не сравнивать. Более быстрый вариант - это проверить её длину: `length $_`. Хотя более короткая запись будет: `length`, - т.к. она работает с `$_`, если аргументы не передали явно. Так можно не писать: `defined && length`, - т.к. length тоже делает проверку на defined

Comment: @EugenKonkov Привет! Добавь это в свой ответ и он станет идеальным :)

Comment: @nörbörnën: Зачем? в вопросе не спрашивают об этом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` используется для фильтрации элементов массива

Обычно при фильтрации мы задаём условие того, какие элементы нам подходят:

```
grep{ $_ > 10 } @arr; # Всё, что больше 10
```

В вашем случае у вас останутся только TRUE элементы: не ноль, не пустая строка, не undefined